# Why am i geeting a syntax error on random.randint()?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently started trying to learn python, and found this small dice program online:

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = 'yes'

while roll_again == 'yes' or roll_again == 'y':
    print ('rolling the dices...')
    print ('The values are...')
    print random.randint(min, max)
    print random.randint(min, max)

    roll_again = raw_input('Roll the dice again?')
```

However, when trying to execute the program i get a syntax error on the first `print random.randint(min, max)` line, saying it's an invalid syntax. I've looked around online for answers, but I haven't been able to find any solutions. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You are using Python 3, the program you found is in Python 2. Just put parantheses around the call to `random.randint` and you should be fine. Oh, and rename `raw_input` to `input`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random.random invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977276/random-random-invalid-syntax)

Comment: Alright, I inserted the parentheses around `random.randint()` and renamed `raw_input` to `input`, and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's python 3. you should use parenthesis for the print statement.